# using imagick class results in "no data received"

Tags: php, imagick

i have a simple question, i started using imagick and using command line arguments does work but trying to do something like:

```
<?php
header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
$image = new Imagick(); 
$image->readImage("meiwen.jpg");
$image->blurImage(5,3);
echo $image;
?>
```

results in the visual studio just in time debugger being called with 
unhandled win 32 exception in httpd.exe, and if i click on "no" or "continue" my browser, chrome returns this: "No data received
Unable to load the webpage because the server sent no data.
Here are some suggestions:
Reload this webpage later.
Error 324 (net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE): The server closed the connection without sending any data."  why does this happen? is there a way to fix this? Thanks in  advance.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have ImageMagick installed? It's not a default package.

I've never used it, but it sounds like it can be a little bit of a pain to get running. This seems like a decent overview of how to do it:
http://alexdespaindev.blogspot.com/2012/02/wamp-server-and-imagemagick.html

Comment: yes, i do have imagcik installed, i run phpinfo() and it showed that i do have imagick installed.